# 2018 Ram Rebel 4x4, can you turn your outer tie rod end upside down for clearance issues?

Tags: ram, tie-rod

2018 Ram Rebel 4X4 crew cab with lift kit 18 x 12 rims with a negative 44 offset rims slightly rub on tie rod ends

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: How about a wheel spacer to move the wheels out slightly?

Answer (score 2):

No, you unfortunately cannot turn your tie rods upside down. The reason is, the post in the middle of the tie rod is tapered. If you tried to put it in upside down, the taper wouldn't seat properly.

[image]